# How many times same date occurs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table column with dates that corresponds to sending order in my company. It is formatted like this `2019-07-31 09:52:09.427`.

```
ModDate

2019-07-31 09:48:08.810    
2019-07-31 09:48:09.000    
2019-07-31 09:48:09.070    
2019-07-31 09:48:08.070    
2019-07-31 09:48:45.083    
2016-09-09 13:13:30.680    
2016-09-09 13:15:00.907    
2016-09-09 13:27:45.647    
2016-09-09 13:32:15.217    
2016-09-09 14:32:15.917    
2016-09-09 14:32:15.917
```

I would like to have a SQL table that counts how many orders where send on specific date like:

```
Date            Number of sent orders
2019-07-31      23
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `count` and `cast` `datetime` as `date`

```
 select cast ( ModDate as date) as d ,count(*) from t
group by cast ( ModDate as date)
```

Answer (score 3):

You may try this, this will give you result for count of each distinct date.

```
  select distinct cast(ModDate as date) as Date, count(ModDate) as [Count] from table group by cast(ModDate as date)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this query

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATE,CreatedDate) as [DateTime], COUNT(*) as [Count]
FROM Orders
GROUP BY CONVERT(DATE,CreatedDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
select moddate ,count(*) over (partition by cast (ModDate as date)) from yourtable
```